# Need to change url using php

Tags: php

I am going to make a URL checking system.

I have this URL
https://lasvegas.craigslist.org/mob/6169799901.html

Now I want to make this URL like this

https://lasvegas.craigslist.org/search/mob?query=6169799901

how can I do it using PHP?

Comment: I think you want [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to consume the URL, then [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to construct it the way you want. You could try fiddling with string methods, but these two should work.

Comment: Add more details

Comment: @FirstOne - https://3v4l.org/E6Y54 Scratch the `http_build_query()`, I meant [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

Answer (score 1):

Since I ended up (maybe?) solving it anyways, here's one method using URL/path parsing:

```
$url = 'https://lasvegas.craigslist.org/mob/6169799901.html';
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$basepath = pathinfo($parsed['path']);

echo $parsed['scheme'].
     "://".
     $parsed['host'].
     "/search".
     $basepath['dirname'].
     "?query=".
     $basepath['filename'];
```

Formatted for readability.

https://3v4l.org/E6Y54

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$url = "https://lasvegas.craigslist.org/mob/6169799901.html";
$id = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
$id =  str_replace(".html","",$id);

$result = "https://lasvegas.craigslist.org/search/mob?query=".$id;
echo $result;
```